# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str Python 3.7.1

Tags: python

```
#This is a comment.
print("Hello,My name is Shuaib Aliyu")
result = ''
message = ''
choice = ''


while choice !=0:
        choice = input("\nDo you want to encrypt or decrypt the message?\nEnter 1 to encrypt, 2 to decrypt and 0 to exit the program. ")

        if choice == '1':
                message = input("\nEnter message for encryption ")
                for i in range(0, len(message)):
                        result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - 2)

                print(result + '\n\n')  
                result = ''

        if choice == '2':
                message = input("\nEnter the message to decreypt: ")
                for i in range(0, len(message)):
                        result = result + chr(ord(message[i] + 2)

                print(result + '\n\n')
                result = ''

        if choice == '0':
                print("You have entered an invalid imput!. Please try again. \n\n")
```

Im trying to do a simple encryption code for a final in one of my classes. I continue to get error after error and i cant figure out whats wrong. Can anyone help me

Comment: To paste the code just simply hit edit then paste it in there then highlight it again and Hit Ctrl-K

Comment: Not really sure what issue is, I ran your code with no issues (Both on Python 3.4 and 3.7.1). `dog` resulted in `bme` when encrypting, and vice versa when decrypting. You should change your `while` loop condition though, you are currently checking for `0` integer value but when user enters their choice it will be `'0'` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the closing parenthesis is wrong for `ord` in route of `choice=='2'`

Your code:

```
chr(ord(message[i] + 2))
```

Correct one:

```
chr(ord(message[i]) + 2)
```

You got the error because you do `+` operation before you cast character to integer.

Comment: when i make that change,it tells me print on the next line is an invalid syntax

Comment: Maybe you are missing close parenthesis. Your code `result = result + chr(ord(message[i] + 2)` has no closing parenthesis for `chr`.